# Why `eval $VERSION` in perl5?

Tags: perl

What's the point of [this....](https://metacpan.org/source/GBJK/Catalyst-Model-DBIC-Schema-0.65/lib/Catalyst/Helper/Model/DBIC/Schema.pm#L7)

```
our $VERSION = '0.65';
$VERSION = eval $VERSION;
```

I don't understand how that's different from..

```
our $VERSION = '0.65';
```

Comment: See [eval $VERSION in modules?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=815646) on PerlMonks (and [Version numbers should be boring](http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/369/version-numbers-should-be-boring/), which is linked from there).

Comment: @EvanCarroll At least you've gone from 0.01 to 0.65? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

our $VERSION = "0.001_001";
print "$VERSION == 0.001_001\n";
$VERSION = eval $VERSION;
print "$VERSION == 0.001_001\n";
```

The reason can be found here...

http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/369/version-numbers-should-be-boring/

The above is a long read though, what the `eval` did was make it possible to compare the VERSION numerically ie it removed the `_`.